# Djangorestframework - All api paths under a common url base

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

django 2.1, python 3.6, djangorestframework

Is it possible to create one api path that includes multiple models?

```
urlpatterns = [
   ...
    path('api/', include('cards.api.urls')),
    path('api2/', include('decks.api.urls')),
]

urlpatterns = [
   ...
    path('api/', include('cards.api.urls', 'decks.api.urls')),
]
```

I am getting the following error messaage

```
Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.
```

I want to be able to have all of my api calls under one url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use,

```
urlpatterns = [
   ...
    path('api/', include('cards.api.urls')),
    path('api/', include('decks.api.urls')),
]
```